# sockect.io difference between creating http server and not creating http

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to create a new notifier system using nodejs, for that i am using socket.io. what is the difference between the below two codings.

Coding 1: //Created a HTTP server and Socket connection

```
var app = require('express').createServer() 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app); 
app.listen(8080);
```

Coding 2: //only created Socket connection

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
```

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference. The latter is merely a shortcut for the former.

One tiny difference does exist though: The shortcut will add a default HTTP request handler (for non-websocket requests) that responds with `Welcome to socket.io.`.